# chown doesn't work permanently

Tags: 14.04

I've set up a Ubuntu Server 14.04 instance including Mate Desktop in AWS EC2. It has a 30GB system volume and a 80GB volume which is available at `/mnt`.

After calling `sudo chown <awsuser> /mnt` I can create files and folders on the 80GB volume.

After rebooting the VM I have to re-run `sudo chown <awsuser> /mnt` otherwise I get a permission denied error.

How can I make `sudo chown <awsuser> /mnt` permanent?

Update:
Output of `mount | grep /mnt`:

```
/dev/xvdb on /mnt type ext3 (rw)
```

Output of `ls -ld /mnt`

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Nov 23  2015 /mnt
```

Comment: Please show us the output of `mount | grep /mnt`.

Comment: @ByteCommander updated my question

Comment: Strange. And what does `ls -ld /mnt` say *before* you chowned the directory?

Comment: Updated the question again

Comment: Looks okay to me. Sorry, I have no more idea... :-/

Comment: Looks like its EC2 behavior: Restarting the instance keeps the volume. Stopping and starting it completely removes that data on the volume.

Comment: Looks like this answers the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11566223/what-data-is-stored-in-ephemeral-storage-of-amazon-ec2-instance

Comment: You should post an answer to your own question containing this link and a short description of its content. You may then accept it after 2 days. Thanks!

Comment: @ByteCommander done, thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/mnt` points to an instance storage. Instance storage is tied to the instance lifecycle as pointed out in the docs:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html#instance-store-lifetime

> You can specify instance store volumes for an instance only when you launch it. The data in an instance store persists only during the lifetime of its associated instance. If an instance reboots (intentionally or unintentionally), data in the instance store persists. However, data in the instance store is lost under the following circumstances:
>
> - The underlying disk drive fails
> - The instance stops
> - The instance terminates
>
> Therefore, do not rely on instance store for valuable, long-term data. Instead, you can build a degree of redundancy (for example, RAID 1/5/6), or use a file system (for example, HDFS and MapR-FS) that supports redundancy and fault tolerance. You can also back up data periodically to more durable data storage solutions such as Amazon S3 or Amazon EBS.

Answer (score 0):

After `sudo chown <awsuser> /mnt`

```
chattr -i /mnt
```

It makes changes permanent and revertible only by root.